# Devpi REST API - How to retrieve versions of packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, devpi

I'm trying to retrieve versions of all packages from specific index. I'm trying to sending GET request with /user/index/+api suffix but it not responding nothing intresting. I can't find docs about devpi rest api.

Has anyone idea how could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add header Accept: application/json - it's working!